# Inheritance issue scipy.stats.pareto

Tags: python, inheritance, scipy

I have the following class (which I will use to extend the existing class `scipy.stats.pareto`):

```
class pareto(scipy.stats.pareto):
    def __init__(self, b):
        super().init(b)
        return
```

when I now run the following code:

```
u=pareto(2)
u.cdf(1)
```

I get an error. However when I run the following code:

```
u=scipy.stats.pareto(2)
u.cdf(1)
```

the code runs and returns `0.0`. I would expect the first code snippet to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.stats.pareto` is not a class.  It is an instance of class:

```
scipy.stats.distributions.pareto_gen
```

We can build a similar interface for our own class like:

#### Code:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

class pareto(stats.distributions.pareto_gen):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # get a `pareto` instance
        self = stats.distributions.pareto_gen(a=1.0, name="pareto")

        # call the instance with desired setup
        return self(*args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # already called __init__()
        pass
```

#### Test Code:

```
u = stats.pareto(2)
print(u.cdf(1))

u = pareto(2)
print(u.cdf(1))
```

#### Results:

```
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: Awesome, had no idea that this was the problem! Thank you very much!